# PHP Array to string conversion

Tags: php, arrays, string, pdo

So I made a query which returns many restaurants and I put them in a variable $row:

```
<?php if(count($Result_restaurants)>0)
{
   foreach($Result_restaurants as $row)
    { ?>
      <div id="ForEveryRestaurant">
      <?php
      $Rest_Name = $row['name'];
      //$Rest_Name = $row;
      $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT Restaurant.idRestaurant FROM Restaurant WHERE Restaurant.name = \"$Rest_Name\"");
      $stmt->execute();
      $idRestaurant = $stmt->fetch();

      $avg = 0;
      $rateSum = 0;
      $strcard = "SELECT rating FROM Review WHERE Review.idRestaurant = $idRestaurant";
      $stmtcard = $db->prepare($strcard);
      $stmtcard->execute();
      $result = $stmtcard->fetchAll();
      if (count($result) === 0) 
      {
        return 0;
      }
      foreach( $result as $coments) 
      {
        $rateSum += $coments['rating'];
      }
      $avg = $rateSum / count($result);
      $avg = round($avg, 1);
```

When I try to run my code, it prints Array to string conversion.

The problem appears in this line:

```
$strcard = "SELECT rating FROM Review WHERE Review.idRestaurant = $idRestaurant";
```

I searched about the error and I understand but I tried many resolutions and didn't solved the problem.

can someone help please?

Comment: `var_dump($idRestaurant);`? If the problem is really in the `"SELECT rating FROM Review WHERE Review.idRestaurant = $idRestaurant"` string, then `$idRestaurant` is an array. But `mysqli_stmt_fetch` returns `bool`. You should bind the result variables instead.

Comment: whats up with the dereference answers? teach the OP first how to use prepared statements properly, dont interpolate variables directly into query statements, use placeholders in your statement and bound the variables with just a simple `->bindValue` method. whats the use having prepared statements if you're just going to use them directly into the string, its like having to use a crowbar to pound the nail

Comment: Why is every answer in this thread get down-voted?

Comment: @Ronald read [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) for the explanation for downvote.

Comment: if i'd guess you're better off rewriting the whole thing and use join statements instead

Comment: The best thing is print your query in the sql and check what is the result. If it is a single element array just extract the value manually .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do like the following

```
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->bind_result($idRestaurant);
 $stmt->fetch();
```

Try For PDO:

```
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$idRestaurant = $result['idRestaurant'];
```

Comment: ok so I did that and It tells me that I have "undefined method of bind result"... that doesnt make sence.

Comment: fyi: the OP is using the PDO interface

Comment: @Ghost that is news. looks like an example of how to ask a bad question

Comment: Yes I am usein PDO interface.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
$idRestaurant = $stmt->fetch();
// Its an array and you cannot use an array directly with WHERE clause in a query. Convert it to normal variable and use it.

$strcard = "SELECT rating FROM Review WHERE Review.idRestaurant = $idRestaurant";    
// here you are using the array in WHERE clause
```

To do this:

```
$rating = isset($stmt->fetch()[0]) ? $stmt->fetch()[0]: null;
```

Comment: how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this statement

```
$idRestaurant = $stmt->fetch();
```

Have you tried `$idRestaurant = $stmt->fetch()[0];`?

You can actually check what's coming into `$idResturant` by checking it via `var_dump`

```
var_dump($idResturant)
```

Comment: `$stmt->fetch()[0]` only exists if `true[0]` exists

Comment: it gives me a: Undefined offset: 0 after I make those changes.

Comment: do this `$idRestaurant = $stmt->fetch(); var_dump($idRestaurant);` and check the results

Comment: @progrAmmar array(1) { ["idRestaurant"]=> string(1) "1" }

Comment: Yep so you can use it as `"SELECT rating FROM Review WHERE Review.idRestaurant = $idRestaurant[0]"` OR `"SELECT rating FROM Review WHERE Review.idRestaurant = $idRestaurant['idRestaurant']"`